# Infinite set with discrete metric is bounded?

Tags: general-topology

Why is that valid? 
I cannot really imagine such a set, so maybe that's where the problem is coming from. I can only imagine 4 points in (a 3D) space that are different and 1 unit away from each other, but not an infinite number of points; in higher-dimensional space there are probably more points. I can imagine every point encompassed within an arbitrarily small ball, but infinite points would require infinite balls...

Comment: This goes to show that the definition of metric is a flexible one: The strong condition which we never can drop is the triangle inequality condition, which is key to every metric, and is clear in this case. The metric is bounded by the way it is defined: it cannot take values more than one! Further, there are many more distances than just the Euclidean distance you can think about , so you should read up some of these fascinating metrics, especially the SNCF metric. The metric is an abstract concept:attempting to visualize it may not be very helpful for higher mathematics.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$ there are at most $n+1$ points which all induce unit distances. You need another approach to imagine infinite set with discrete metric. As for why this is valid, this is trivial from the [definition of a bounded set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Metric_space).

Comment: The Euclidean spaces are too special to be a good mental model for metric spaces in general.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, I will look more into that.

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: @boreora Do look into it. I went to Paris a few years back , and I can see where the SNCF gets it's name from.